# My SO question was marked incorrectly as a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I know this is a topic that's come up a few times on Meta, but I have no idea what else to do at this point.

I spent a week trying to solve this, none of the existing resources helped. Finally I posted it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255371/d3-update-circle-pack-data-new-nodes-overlap-existing-nodes) only to have it shut down as a duplicate within a few hours. The person who marked it as such might not have fully understood what I was asking and how this was different from the case he assumed this duplicated.

Given that I was following an established d3 update pattern, and a built-in layout, I really hoped that posting my question would reach an audience where someone could help me. I updated my question with additional information explaining how the linked solution doesn't work.

Some similar posts on Meta say that once a question is updated, someone can unmark it as a duplicate. This has not happened in the weeks since I updated it.

Is there anything else I can do at this point?

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment? I'm not proficient enough in the field to judge the situation, but if anyone from the JS tag is willing to vouch for the question's not-duplicate-ness, I'll be happy to throw in my reopen vote. This seems like a somewhat legit case where the duplicate suggestion doesn't work for the OP, no?

Comment: I *suspect* that the final sentence may be somewhat responsible for some of the downvotes. It doesn't add anything to the question, but makes the whole thing come over as much more hostile.

Comment: @JonSkeet I' m no expert in d3.is or java-script, but the question seems to be answered with the dupe, unless clarified, why not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't know - I can't say either way, to be honest. I can't tell whether it's genuinely a different *question*, or whether the OP is effectively just saying that the accepted answer doesn't work - which would have been better either as a comment, or possibly specifying it in the new question. (I don't have enough knowledge to see whether the OP has correctly implemented the answer ,even.) But assuming that the closer's opinion was "rushed and informed" doesn't seem like a constructive approach.

Comment: That python expert might be uninformed, but that's really *your* problem.  A giant screenshot and a single line of code does exceedingly little to demonstrate the problem and inform SO users.  Read [this Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited people. Could we step past that unfortunate sentence now and address the legitimate question? Is it a dupe, and if not, how can the OP improve the post to see it reopened?

Comment: Ok sorry for coming off harsh in my question by assuming the decision to close my question was rushed. Thanks for editing that out. I still think it's a legitimately different question and I will continue to add more information to it. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done the right thing by editing and explaining why that answer doesn't work. So maybe other users with expert knowledge in that area will vote to reopen.

> Is there anything else I can do at this point?

You can ping the closer, @username, to explain that the dupe doesn't work and to consider reopening. I have done this when I have incorrectly closed as a dupe and the user explains how the dupe isn't relevant. Sometimes not enough information is given in the first revision of a post which makes it look like an exact dupe of another post.

Editing to clarify better *exactly* how/why the dupe doesn't work may also help your case with reviewers.

Another option is to ask in a related chat room if the users there agree with you. Note that in joining a chat room, you should read and follow the rules of that room, be polite, and accept their decision after a polite conversation on the issue. Also, know that the users there aren't obligated to discuss it at all but if you bring it up in a good way then they are likely to address it.

> Does one person's rushed and uninformed opinion really get to determine the overall worthiness of a question?

That's a little harsh. The user was uninformed because your initial post didn't make mention of using that method and that it doesn't work for you. Also, the user holds a gold badge in one of those tags which means the user has shown adequate knowledge in that area to make those decisions based on SO criteria. The user is also not determining the worthiness of the question but rather trying to be helpful and say, "Your answer, and the answer for anyone with a similar question, has already been posted if you care to follow this link".

Comment: I'm not certain the user would be notified of such a ping?

Comment: @Bart I thought for sure they were and that I've been notified, notified others this way. But I may be wrong

Comment: @Bart As a duplicate closer, you are in the "comment history" and so can be notified by pings.

Comment: Only the dupehammer closers @Bradley, from what I remember... Which is what happened here.

Comment: @Ben, That, or the initial duplicate suggestor (since it generates a comment for that)

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I added a comment with @ the guy who duped it and elaborated on why the "solution" doesn't solve my specific issue.

Comment: @Ben is there a way to tell who the original duplicate marker was for the purposes of pinging?

Comment: From what I understand @Scott, you can only @ ping close voters in comments who are either gold badge holders (and therefore your question is closed) who or were the first close voter (before your question is closed) because the first close voter creates a duplicate comment.

Comment: @Ben So if there are multiple close voters ([.e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018108/python-round-scalar-up-to-nearest-non-integer-value)), then there is no way to tell, it would seem.

Comment: For that question you could ping tripleee @scott, who closed the question with their gold badge. tripleee also has the ability to _open_ the question with a single vote for the same reason, so is the best person who's interacted with the question to ping. Ensure you explain why. I'd also time the current implementation and then explain what you expect the timings to be in order to achive your goals. When you edit it'll be put in the reopen queue. Ping me somewhere when you do and I'll vote to reopen too. Don't want to in advance as people won't see the best version of your question.